# Package 'rowr' was removed from the CRAN repository. Is there any solution or substitution for rowr package?

Tags: r, shinyapps

Now I am facing problem while deploying app on shinyapp.io .

Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application:

> ```
> 1177465...Warning in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
>   **Unable to find repository URL for package rowr**
> ```

above  error comes while deploying app on server. please suggest.

Comment: Which function do you use from `rowr` ?

Comment: I am using rowsum() in my code

Comment: How can we deploy shiny app  using  archive functions of CRAN repository.

Comment: I don't find `rowsum` in the source code.  I think you can't deploy on shinyapps.io with an archived package. Your best option is to write this function.